# Update existing document of Elasticsearch and insert current record through logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am trying to insert a record into elasticsearch and also update a field of an existing document whose _id I'll be getting from the current record. After searching online, I found that we can use the _update_by_query api with the http plugin in logstash. This is the below configuration.

```
output {

    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "my_index_*"
            document_id => "%{id_field}"
       }

    http {
           url => "http://localhost:9200/my_index_*/_update_by_query"
           http_method => "post"
           content_type => "application/json"
           format => "message"
           message => '{"query":{"match":{"_id":"%{previous_record_id}"}},"script":{"source":"ctx._source.field_to_be_updated=xyz","lang":"painless"}}'

       }
}
```

The Elasticsearch has no password protection and so I haven't added an authorization header.
But when I start logstash, the current record gets inserted but I always the below error for the http plugin.

```
2022-05-05T11:31:51,916][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ][logstash_txe] [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 400 {:response_code=>400, :url=>"http://localhost:9200/my_index_*/_update_by_query", :event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x192606f8>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not how you're supposed to do it, you can simply use the `elasticsearch` output for both use cases.

The first one for indexing a new record and the following one for partial updating another record whose id is `previous_record_id`. The event data can be accessed in `params.event` within the script:

```
elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "my_index_xyz"
   document_id => "%{previous_record_id}"
   action => "update"

   script => "ctx._source.field_to_be_updated = params.event.xyz"
   script_lang => "painless"
   script_type => "inline"
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have tried this but I still get the following error.
 {:status=>400, :action=>["update", {:_id=>"00002", :_index=>"my_index_*", :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc", :retry_on_conflict=>1}, #<LogStash::Event:0x62a1a697>], :response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"my_index_*", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"00002", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"invalid_index_name_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid index name [data_lake_*], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"my_index_*"}}}}
It says the index must not contain '*' .

Comment: The index name must be concrete, it cannot be an alias or a wildcard index name like `my_index_*`.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know in which index the document is stored and hence I thought an update_by_query would be a better way. Any other alternate approach you can think of?

Comment: Are your indexes time-based? If yes, how do you decide which index the new document gets initially indexed into?

Comment: Yes they are! We store them in index based on year and week number from a timestamp field we get in the record. Ex: my_index_2022w18. So are you suggesting we get the index name and use that index in elasticsearch output plugin? I thought of that too. We will be querying for that record using the elasticsearch filter plugin and from the response, store the index name?

Comment: How do you get `previous_record_id`? Do you also have the timestamp of that record?

Comment: We get the `previous_record_id` from the current record but not the timestamp of the previous record. The only way to search for the previous record is by using that id and query it across all indices. I'm not sure if we can do that in the filter plugin and get the index name of that previous record.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do it with an `elasticsearch` filter, you should try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Here is what I have done. 
`elasticsearch { hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
 query => "_id:%{previous_record_id}"
  index => "my_index"
 fields => { "timestamp" => "previousRecordsTime" }
}`
I queried for it and got the timestamp of the previous record, generated the index of the previous record based on it and updated it using the script. One important thing I've noticed is that, after querying, it was not possible to get the index name of the query response. Tried `{ "_index" => "prevIndex" }` but was giving null. But this thing worked now, thanks a lot